# Anylogic: How to stop timeout in a delay block with condition?

Tags: java, timeout, delay, anylogic

I have a collection that counts the number of passengers that enter on a boat at the port.
The max capacity of the boat is 1750 and it's scheduled to leave the port every 120 minutes, I would like to end the timeout and let the boat leave the port if the boat reaches the max capacity earlier than 120 minutes.

I've used a delay block, but if I choose Type -> "Specified time" I cannot stop the delay and if I choose Type -> "Until stopDelay is called" I cannot set a specific timeout.

Is Delay the right block to use? How can I set the condition above?

Thanks a lot in advance.

[Click to see passengers and boat flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehQEm.png)

Comment: Is this a multi-threaded program?

Comment: Hello Moish, since I don't know what you are talking about, I've added an image of the flow. Hope it will help to answer your question.

Comment: @Moish this is not about multi-threading, although it may look like it to Java coders. This is about a simulation tool "AnyLogic" that is single-threaded :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Wait block and manually trigger `wait.free(myBoat)` when either of the conditions is met. The timeout can be done with an event (or better a Dynamic Event). The other condition is driven from your passengers so they would need to call the `free()` method.